# Solved: Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw option list on input line 252

Tags: pdftex, koma-script

All of a sudden running PdfLaTeX I get this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.6.13)  15 JUN 2021 23:48
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\makeatletter\def\cathedral@pagesize{a5}\makeatother\makeatletter \newcommand
{\select@version}{\version@final} \makeatother\newif\ifStatisticSelected\Statis
ticSelectedfalse\newif\ifFinalSelected\FinalSelectedtrue\newif\ifDraftSelected\
DraftSelectedfalse\newif\ifKindleSelected\KindleSelectedfalse\AtBeginDocument{\
SetWatermarkText{}}\input Een-halve-Surinamer-D.tex
 (./Een-halve-Surinamer-D.tex
(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)

(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2021/03/17 v3.33 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(/zfs/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] compatibility for LaTeX before 2021/05/01 on inpu
t line 337.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.580 \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}
                                 \relax
```

This is with TL2021. Wenn using TL2020 it compiles smoothly. Both TL updated.

Can somebody give me a hint in what direction to go to solve this (apart from just using TL2020)?

Here is the minimal example Ulrike asked for:

```
\documentclass[%
\iffalse% 
parskip=half,%
\fi%
]{scrbook}
%
\begin{document}
%
\end{document}
```

This compiles on TL2020. and also on TL2021 when `\iffalse` and `\fi` are removed. As the example also compiles for class *book*, I think it is a bug in the KOMA class scrbook.

Comment: start by creating a small complete example that demonstrates the error that can be used for tests.

Comment: you should not get that error in any case, but you appear to be using `latexrelease` to roll latex back to an earlier version?

Comment: No. A `find . -exec grep latexrelease {} \; 2>/dev/null` in my LaTeX tree showed nothing. I'll add some more log lines to my question

Comment: Why do you ask for help and then ignore the comments you get? Show an example, that we can use to test if we can reproduce the problem. As the error happens early it should be easy to give a short one: only the start of the preamble really matters.

Comment: @Ulrike: I normally do! But this is a complicated case, using makefiles to generate different views. When I strip it down to make it simple, the error does not occur anymore. Because the error looked peculiar to me, I just tried a shot in case someone could say something helpful. I am working at it. Thanks for your input

Comment: This happens because, at some point in keyval processing, the option list is split at the comma, and eventually only the `\iffalse` is expanded without a matching `\fi`.

Comment: Are you sure? Removing the comma yields the same error.

Comment: @Jack Not the same error! Removing the comma, the parser then splits at the `=`, and that will give you an option called `\iffalse parskip`, which is then used as in `\@ifundefined{\iffalse parskip}`, which then fails. I'd suggest you perform the logic outside of the option parsing. Something like `\expanded{\noexpand\documentclass[\iffalse parskip=half,\fi]{scrbook}}`.

Comment: @Phelype: OK. It seems to work on my complexer documents. The question remains: Since about 10 years (or even more) this construct worked. Since the update to TL2021 not anymore. I suspect that some change in KOMA caused this. But I will adapt all my documents and hope they last at least 10 years. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jack You went 10 years relying on an implementation detail of how the option list was parsed. Previously it worked because the option list parser did the equivalent of the `\expanded` code above right at the beginning, but now it saves the options prior to doing that, and this makes the parser get confused about the unbalanced `\iffalse`. Using the `\expanded` trick above will force-expand the `\iffalse...\fi` before the option parsing kicks in, so there is no reason for that to stop working, so you can bet a few more decades on that

Comment: Wow! Isn't the World of TeX a wonderful one? With surprises every now and then, but reliable for the faithful.